# How to run bash command without stalling my terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I want to run an app that stalls my terminal but then I need to use that terminal again and can't have it stall, is there some sort of prefix I can apply to a command that will allow it to run asynchronously? Example:

```
async mousepad
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. General Linux usage questions should be posted to [unix.se] or [su] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `&` to make the program run in the background.

From the `bash` [manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists):

> If a command is terminated by the control operator `&`, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell. The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return       status is `0`. These are referred to as asynchronous commands.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it in the background. Haven't tried it with that mousepad command but hopefully this works.

```
nohup "COMMAND" &
```

or

```
nohup async mousepad &
```

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-run-linux-commands-in-background/

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it in the background. The `screen` tool is recommended

Screen supports `session recovery`, `multi window` and `session sharing`

- Session recovery

> As long as the screen itself is not terminated, the session running inside it can be resumed. This is especially useful for remote login users - even if the network connection is interrupted, the user will not lose control of the opened command line session. Just log in to the host again and execute screen - r to resume the operation of the session. Similarly, when you leave temporarily, you can also execute the detach command detach to suspend the screen (switch to the background) while ensuring the normal operation of the program inside. This is very similar to VNC in the graphical interface.

- Multi window

> In the screen environment, all sessions run independently and have their own number, input, output and window cache. Users can switch between different windows through shortcut keys, and can freely redirect the input and output of each window. Screen realizes basic text operations, such as copy and paste; It also provides a function similar to scroll bar, which can view the history of window status. Windows can also be partitioned and named, and the activity of background windows can be monitored.

- Session sharing

> Screen allows one or more users to log in to a session multiple times from different terminals and share all the features of the session (for example, you can see exactly the same output). It also provides the mechanism of window access permission, which can protect the window with password.